# Using lme4 for random effect

Tags: r, lme4

I have 3 random variables, x, y z ( all random effect)

x is nested in y, but y is crossed in z

I use the following function in lme4, but it does not work.

```
<- lmer(A ~ 1 + (1 | x/y) + (1 | y*z) + (1|x/y*z), my data)
```

Does anyone help me? Many thanks

Comment: `my data` cannot be the name of the data frame. And start with a MUCH simpler model, check if it runs. "It does not work" is not very useful to get a good response. Show the whole working example, boiled down to the minimum.

Comment: my data is the matrix which is used in lme4. This is correct, I suppose as it does work with other models. This function does not work when variables are nested with other variables. My questions is the function used. How we address the nested variables in the function.

Comment: *please* specify what "does not work" means ...

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid this is still very unclear.  More context would be useful.  My guess is that you want

```
A ~ 1 + (1|y)+ (1|z) + (1|y:z) + (1|y:x)
```

or equivalently

```
A ~ 1 + (1|y*z) + (1|y:x)
```

but it's almost impossible to know for sure.

- the first two random effects terms give among-y and among-z variances
- the third term gives the variance among combinations of y and z -- you will only want this if you have multiple observations for each {y,z} combination
- the last term gives the effect of x nested within y.

The  expression `A ~ 1 + (1|y/x) + (1|z/y)` should give you the same results, because `a/b` expands in general to `a + a:b` (order matters for `/` but not for `:`), but it's less clear.

Crossed random effects are generally denoted by `(1|y) + (1|z)`, or by `(1|y*z)` (which expands to `(1|y) + (1|z) + (1|y:z)`) *if* as discussed above there are multiple observations per {y,z} combination.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ben, very useful. in my model, y is crossed in z. I do not see y*z in the function, would you please clarify it.

Comment: Thank You Ben, random effect should be coded, as say 1, 2, 3, 4,... is that correct?

Comment: the grouping variables (`x`, `y`, `z`) should ideally be *factors*, but lme4 will convert them if they're not.  (If you don't know what a factor is, it would probably be a good idea to read some introductory R material ...)

Comment: I am sorry Ben, but crossed random effects using (1|y*z)  does not work. The sign of * meaningful for lme4. For example, if x is crossed in y and y is crossed in z, using *  will not work. Would you give a further input please. Many thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help further unless you can give more context/ explain your problem/experimental design more precisely.  What *precisely* does "x is crossed in y and y is crossed in z" mean?

Comment: Thanks Ben, x, y and z  are  random effects. The  experimental design is x*y*z. Consider people(x) received marks by teachers (y) in math and geometry (z).

Comment: Please edit your question according to clarify the following ... I understand the "marks" is the response variable (continuous, plausibly Normally distributed), and that "people" and "teachers" are two (crossed) grouping variables for random effects; if math vs. geometry can be considered as two levels of a categorical predictor, they should probably be treating as two *fixed* effects (possibly crossed with teacher and with pupil).  I assume each pupil gets at most one mark in each subject from each teacher?

Comment: Thank you Ben, That's correct. would  you please let me know how I can write the function using lme4. I have used the sign of "*", but it says it is meaningful.

Comment: sorry, it says it is NOT meaningful

Comment: please edit your question to include the information I gave above.  Please edit your question to include information about what "does not work" (information in the comments is transient, it's best to include all information relevant to the question in the body of the question itself)